# How to add a search bar to a table view that is populated from a plist

Tags: iphone, xcode, search, plist

I have tried using a couple of different search bar examples but I have not had any luck with adding a search bar.  I would really appreciate any help that can be provided.  The following is the code and I was using the search bar controller example.

```
         if(CurrentLevel == 0) {

            //Initialize our table data source
            NSArray *tempDict = [[NSArray alloc] init];
            self.tableDataSource = tempDict;
            [tempDict release];


            Midwest_DigestiveAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (Midwest_DigestiveAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Rows"];  

            //Initialize the array.
            NSMutableArray *listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


            [listOfItems addObjectsFromArray:tableDataSource];

            //Initialize the copy array.
            NSMutableArray *copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


            //Add the search bar
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
            searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

            searching = NO;
            letUserSelectRow = YES;

        }
         else 
            self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;   


         //Initialize the array.
        NSMutableArray *listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initW];

            [listOfItems addObjectsFromArray:tableDataSource];


        //Initialize the copy array.
        NSMutableArray *copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        //Add the search bar
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
        searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

        searching = NO;
        letUserSelectRow = YES;


    }


    - (void) searchTableView {

        NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
        NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems)
        {
            NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
            [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
        }

        for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
        {
            NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
                [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
        }

        [searchArray release];
        searchArray = nil;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?  What does the app do (or not do) that seems wrong to you?

Comment: I have a plist that displays in a uitableview. The view starts with 2 selections, procedures and education.  It gets this list from the plist. Upon selection it takes you to a list of procedures or information. I would like to add a search bar to each level so that as the list grows it remains searchable.

Comment: a) That is not a programming question, that is a functional requirement.
  b) What have you tried that did not work?  What error messages are you getting?  If you're looking for drop-in code to solve your problem, SO is not the place.  On the other hand, if you say, "I tried x,y, and z, but I get error foo", or "I get no results in my table", or "app crashes in cellForRowAtIndexPath...", THEN maybe we can help you get unstuck.
Cheers.

Comment: I load the table successfully from the plist using self.tableDataSource.  My Overlay works fine but when I click on the search bar and begin to type my table completely disappears. Which means my listOfItems and copyListOfItems are not being populated.  I do not receive an error message.  My plist consist of multiple levels and I would like to be able to search on each level. I've shorten the code to show you my viewDidLoad and searchtableView.

Comment: (In your posted code, line 5 has no effect, since you then overwrite self.tableViewDataSource on line 10.  But that's not the problem.)
  I suggest you put NSLog statements in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: and numberOfRowsInSection: methods, and step through them in the debugger.  These populate your table cells.  Make sure you are getting your data from the array you think you are.